# Something like doxygen for puppet nodes

Tags: puppet

I've got a fairly deep tree of inheritance within my puppet nodes.

Before I head to omnigraffle, is there a tool out there like Doxygen for puppet scripts which could diagram this inheritance tree?

Comment: Inheritance [has been long declared persona non-grata](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_classes.html#inheritance). I'd recommend switching to `hiera` or an ENC.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind. Considering `hiera` at some point, but just getting started atm.

Comment: @quickshiftin I'd say get started with Hiera in the first place instead of fiddling with node inheritance.

Comment: I hear you guys, but coming from a programming background inheritance seems pretty natural to me. I'd even venture to say an inheritance / hiera combo could be pretty slick, but hard to say until I've tried hiera. My presumption is though, why duplicate configuration for each node when it can just be pulled in via inheritance and set in one place.

Comment: OIC, hiera uses yaml and can have inherited/overridden configuration.., will take a look sooner rather than later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154090/puppet-inheritance-vs-puppet-composition

Comment: Started looking at `hiera` today and my brain is hurting. I don't know how anyone could argue it's easier to understand than node inheritance, lol. Maybe cleaner in the end, but **way** more complicated for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet outputs dot files as well. Have you tried using those? Some people find the dot command line difficult to use. [This fellow](http://blog.jasonantman.com/2012/03/python-script-to-find-dependency-cycles-in-graphviz-dot-files/) wrote a Python script to resolve some of the dependency cycles in the dot files that Puppet generates.

If you're frustrated by the lack of control over placement that dot files give you, [this other fellow](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/540/how-to-handle-large-dependency-graphs-without-omnigraffle/) recommends Gephi for manipulating the dot files that Puppet gives you. I'm not sure if he's advertising though--he answered his own question. I've tried Gephi myself just briefly--it looks like it has a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Something about dot is what I was expecting here, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.